# Centering Logo on TinkTank.in Wordpress Site

Tags: php, css, wordpress, center, centering

I'm trying to update the logo for my farm (manayunkfarm.org) and I need to center the logo. I'm wondering if someone could help me understand how I need to do this.

within the style.css under .logo there is this:

```
.logo {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
width: 500px;
height: auto;
margin-left: -4.1665em; }
```

given this info, I'm not sure if you can help me but let me know what else I need to share with you.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That or CSS that will center any div/object as long as it has a width set.

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
```

Comment: This will work, after modifying your code in the editor this is a perfect solution. ALSO, if you are wondering why the selector .logo is not doing anything it is because your selector (.header-home .logo) is overriding your .logo selector

Comment: You will need to remove the .logo selector

Comment: And if you want the logo to go down a bit just add this code (margin-top: 100px;)

Comment: Okay. So where do I remove the .logo selector? Also where do I add the margin-top: 100px;?

Comment: Okay. Figured out where to put the margin-top and every page but the homepage looks perfect.

Comment: ah the homepage... let's see

Comment: you have `float:left` on .logo ?

Comment: sorry was looking at the wrong site.  Your .logo css is being overwritten... http://imgur.com/vHNHddK

Comment: I don't think so. No.

Comment: remove the "left" and "margin-left" attributes from `.header-home`

Comment: Rather from `.header-home .logo` selector.  Sorry about that.  Line 192 in your CSS sheet.

Comment: Okay, it looks like it worked. I just don't now how to bring it back down.

Comment: add a "margin-top" argument to your `.header-home .logo` selector

Comment: It's beautiful! Thank you! Marking as answered.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add this property

**text-align: center;**

Comment: That didn't work. Why would it be "text-align" if it's an image?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the logo was text after looking at your website.